# Dynamically copying package data during install time in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a directory structure which looks like below :

```
.
├── bitbucket-pipelines.yml
├── MANIFEST.in
├── pylintrc
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── project.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── ml_project
│       ├── configurations
│       │   └── precommit
│       ├── core
│       │   ├── command
│       │   │   ├── abs_command.py
│       │   │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   │   ├── no_command.py
│       │   │   ├── precommit.py
│       │   │   ├── project_utils.py
│       │   │   ├── setupsrc.py
│       │   │   └── setuptox.py
│       │   ├── configurations
│       │   │   └── precommit
│       │   └── __init__.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── tox.ini
```

When i do the packaging for the project my requirement is to basically copy the files `.gitlint` and `.pre-commit-config.yaml` files inside the `configurations/precommit` folder of my `ml_project` package. `configurations` is just a normal directory and not a Python package as it does not contain `.py` files.

A small edit the `.gitlint` and `.pre-commit-config.yaml` are in the same level as `setup.py` is.

My `setup.py` looks like below :

```
"""Setup script."""

import io
import re
import os
import shutil
from setuptools import setup

PROJECT_NAME = "ml_project"
CONFIGURATIONS_DIR_NAME = "configurations"
FULL_CONFIG_DIR = os.path.join("src", PROJECT_NAME, CONFIGURATIONS_DIR_NAME)


def get_version() -> str:
    """Return the version stored in `ml_project/__init__.py:__version__`."""
    # see https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/setup.py
    with io.open("src/ml_project/__init__.py", "rt", encoding="utf8") as init_file:
        return re.search(r'__version__ = "(.*?)"', init_file.read()).group(1)


def add_config_files_for_package(source_dir: str = None) -> None:
    if not source_dir:
        source_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    config_files = {"precommit": [".gitlint", ".pre-commit-config.yaml"]}
    for config in config_files:
        config_dir = os.path.join(source_dir, FULL_CONFIG_DIR, config)
        for file in config_files[config]:
            shutil.copyfile(
                os.path.join(source_dir, file), os.path.join(config_dir, file)
            )


add_config_files_for_package()
setup(version=get_version())
```

So i am using the `add_config_files_for_package` function to do the copying when i run `python setup.py sdist`.

I have a `MANIFEST.in` file which looks like below :

```
include .gitlint
include .pre-commit-config.yaml
graft src/ml_project
```

And finally below is my `setup.cfg` :

```
[options]
package_dir =
    =src
packages = find:
include_package_data = true
install_requires =
    click
    pre-commit
    pyyaml
    gitlint


[options.packages.find]
where = src

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    project = bin.project:main

[options.extras_require]
tests =
    pytest
    pytest-mock
    pyfakefs
    pyyaml
    configparser
linting =
    pylint
testdocs =
    pydocstyle
pre-commit =
    pre-commit

[semantic_release]

version_variable = ml_project/__init__.py:__version__
```

This runs fine but my question is : is there a better and more standard way of doing this stuff ? Like without writing the function in the first place at all?

Thanks for any pointers in advance.

Comment: Move them into `src/ml_project/configurations` once and forever, no need to copy them every time. Create symlinks to them in the top-level directory.

Comment: This raises a question: why are you doing this in the first place? These two files don't look like they belong in a Python _source distribution_. Otherwise, same as @phd I believe I would place the files in the `configurations` directory and create _symlinks_ in the root directory (assuming you work only on platforms that support them).

Comment: when i distribute the package i want them copied over inside `configurations/precommit` . That way i don't have to change them twice. This package is used as a command line tool to install hooks into other python packages. So this package is kind of a place to incorporate best practices for precommits

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it could be a good idea to place these files in the `src/ml_project/configurations/precommit` directory and create *symbolic links* to these files at the root of the project. Symbolic links should play well with *git*, but some platforms (*Windows* for example) don't have good support for them.

Or the copy of these files could be just another step in the build process (eventually via a custom *setuptools* command), that should be triggered from a *Makefile* (for example, or any other similar tool), and from the CI/CD toolchains (`bitbucket-pipelines.yml` in this case).